# CartoDB toggle map view - can I share the map as an iFrame?

Tags: carto

I followed the tutorial - [toggle map view](http://developers.cartodb.com/tutorials/toggle_map_view.html) and have successfully made the map.

I'm now wondering what is the best way to share this map? I'd like to be able to give a client an iFrame, can I do this after I've edited the code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can share it with an iframe, CartoDB uses iframes to publish maps

Comment: But I'm altering the code that CartoDB produces, so how do I use CartoDB to publish the map?

Comment: I don't follow you, could you please share the code ?

Comment: The code is exactly what is written here: http://developers.cartodb.com/tutorials/toggle_map_view.html